# Edge correction for density estimation and point pattern analysis by R

Tags: r, point, kernel-density

I have point data and coordinates for study area. By using R, I need to investigate:

1. Density of data by using kernel method (quartic kernel).
2. Choose the best bandwidth by using Mean Square Error (MSE).
3. Calculating G and F functions to investigate is there any patern (clustring or regularization) or the points are distributed randomly.

I have run the code for the kernel method and functions and it works but I realized that I need to do edge correction to avoid distortions caused by the edges, it is necessary to establish a zone between border of the original study area and the sub-region where the analysis is conducted.
(Edit: I mean that I need to create a new sub region to eleminate edge effect. The data I share is the original study region, and I might be wrong but I thought that we need a inner sub-region to eleminate edge effect.)

What is the most suitable way of edge correction for my case and how can I do in R?

I am using the data of bodmin_moor for study area and bodmin_tors for points you can find it here [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/martinez/martinez.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/martinez/martinez.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "t is necessary to establish a zone between border of the original study area and the sub-region where the analysis is conducted."? What's the original study region and the "sub-region"? The data only has one polygonal region.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean that I need to create a new sub region to eleminate edge effect. The data I share is the original study region, and I might be wrong but I thought that we need a inner sub-region to eleminate edge effect.

Comment: That's one way of eliminating edge effects - but you only have 35 points and you probably can't afford a margin to lose any of them. Your kernel estimate is only corrected over the inner area.

Comment: What about G and F function, they need some edge correction right?

Comment: To be unbiased estimators, yes, you can use the same buffer zone method but again with only 35 points I think you'll lose power. Not that it matters much because these points are clearly non-uniform Poisson over the study area.